# jQuery Mobile choose telephone number

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm developing a new JQM app based on Phonegap.

In a page, I have a link like this (work fine):

```
<a href="tel:+1800229933">Call us free!</a>
```

How I can do for add (optional) another telephone number? I would like that user could choose which number to call.

Comment: Can you not just add another link like you already have? Maybe I misunderstand your question.

Comment: pass the var in place of no .

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 2):

Why you don't use a notification? With notification.confirm (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#notification.confirm) the user will get a native dialog and can choose an option.

Here is an example:

```
// process the confirmation dialog result
function onConfirm(buttonIndex) {
    var phone = '0123456789'; // default is an Service Agent
    if (2 === buttonIndex) {
        phone = '0987654321'; // user want's local dealer
    } else if (3 === buttonIndex) {
        phone = '911'; // it's really urgent
    }
    location.href = 'tel:' + phone; // trigger native phonecall
}

// Show a custom confirmation dialog
function showConfirm() {
    navigator.notification.confirm(
        'Do you like an agent or local dealer?', // message
         onConfirm,                              // callback to invoke with index of button pressed
        'Please call us',                        // title
        'Service Agent,Dealer,Emergency'         // buttonLabels
    );
}

// Trigger the click event
$('#yourButton').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    showConfirm();
});
```

Comment: Ok Rwam; if I have three telephones number? (For example an hotel)

Comment: Each button label represent a number: you have three buttons than you can decide between three numbers.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<input type="number" id="number" >
<a id="call">Call us free!</a>
</html
```

>
this is the html

```
var no = $('#number').value;
var call = "tel:+"+no;
$('#call').attr('href', 'call');
```

this will the js part